# hasChildNodes() in method returns false even though the element does have child nodes

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I'm making a quiz creation app that allows me to choose a text area, a text box, a select box, or a set of radio boxes for a specific question. I can add and remove all those input types fine except for the radio boxes. I'm trying to delete individual radio boxes, and to do that I want to use a dynamically generated, numbered DIV element that the radio button, label, and delete button can all append to. Here is the relevant HTML. Each generated DIV with this content will be appended to the DIV with the formDiv ID.

```
   <div style='margin-top: 10px;' class='jumbotron'>
       <form action='#' method='#'>
           <div>
    <input type=’button’ value=’Add component’ id=’addContent’>
    <div id=’chooseContent’ style=’display:none’>
        <ul>
            <li class=’list-group-item’>
                <div id=”textareaOpt”>Text area</div>
            </li>
            <li class=’list-group-item’>
                <div id=”textOpt”>Text box</div>
            </li>
            <li class=’list-group-item’>
                <div id=”selectOpt”>Select</div>
            </li>
            <li class=’list-group-item’>
                <div id=”radioOpt”>Radio</div>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <input type=’button’ id=’cancelContent’ value=’X’>
    </div>
               <div id= 'formDiv'></div>
           </div>
       </form>
   </div>
```

The formDiv element is meant to be the parent element to any input type. I'm dynamically adding radio buttons to a page that are appended to the generated DIV component, and use addDeleteBtn() to create a button to remove the component and I’m trying to append it to the component instead of formDiv. However, addDeleteBtn() doesn't interpret formDiv as having any child elements for it to append to, even though createComponent() does recognize formDiv’s children.

```
function createComponent(){
if(targetType == 'radio'){
  form_content_num++; 
  var component = document.createElement('div');
  component.id = form_content_num; //to dynamically number these divs
  console.log(component);

  var radioLabel = document.createElement('label');
  radioLabel.style.display = 'inline';

  var radioBtn = document.createElement('input');
  radioBtn.style.display = 'inline';
  radioBtn.type = targetType;

  component.appendChild(radioLabel);
  component.appendChild(radioBtn);
  console.log("formDiv.childNodes[0] " + formDiv.childNodes[0]); //this returns true
}

addDeleteBtn();
formDiv.appendChild(component);
console.log("formDiv.childNodes[0] " + formDiv.childNodes[0]); //also returns true
}
function addDeleteBtn(){
  var formDiv = document.getElementById('formDiv');
  console.log("formDiv " + formDiv);
  console.log("hasChildNodes " + formDiv.hasChildNodes()); //returns false
  //code not relevant to this problem was deleted to save space
}
```

Comment: Without the HTML part of this, no one can answer this question. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: it's good to have added the HTML part but we still cannot **REPRODUCE** the context of your question

Comment: this kind of quote on   style= display:none cause error, I think your problem start there

Comment: `hasChildNodes()` works perfectly, your problem is somewhere else...

Answer (score 0):

```
addDeleteBtn();
formDiv.appendChild(component);
```

are in the wrong order. Change it to

```
formDiv.appendChild(component);
addDeleteBtn();
```

Basically when moving the button to the `component` from `formDiv`, the call to `addDeleteBtn` wasn't moved to after `component` was added to the DOM.